# Plotly: getting 'Alert!: HREF in BASE tag is not an absolute URL' error

Tags: python, url, cygwin, url-routing, plotly

**Problem:**

### Is it possible to install/use plotly on Cygwin?

**The Sordid Details:**

I'm following the [getting started](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/) (initial plot display) procedure in `plotly` on `Cygwin.`

No errors are reported from the `pip install` stage, and my credential file `(~/.plotly/.credentials)` looks fine (I've masked some characters here), viz.:

```
$ cat ~/.plotly/.credentials
{
    "username": "roXXXXXak",
    "stream_ids": [
        "suXXXXX16n",
        "nqfXXXXXX5",
        "sXXXXXxj00"
    ],
    "api_key": "2qXXXXXXXv"
}
```

However, when I enter the following in interactive Python:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

trace0 = Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 15, 13, 17]
)
trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[16, 5, 11, 9]
)
data = Data([trace0, trace1])

unique_url = py.plot(data, filename = 'basic-line')
```

plotly is trying to create the plot in a browser window, so it enters me into `lynx` - which asks me to authorize some cookies:

```
plot.ly cookie: csrftok=yUcKFRjIg5CMhW2oQ027QHMePm0 Allow? (Y/N/Always/neVer)
```

but, instead of producing the plot, I get this error:

```
Alert!: HREF in BASE tag is not an absolute URL.
```

???

and this is the `lynx` window I end up in.

[image: plotly in lynx after 'Alert!: HREF in BASE tag is not an absolute URL' error]

**G**oogle **i**s **n**ot **m**y **f**riend, as none of its results hints what is causing this error here (see notes below).

### Can you do better than Google and suggest how to solve this 'not an absolute URL' error?

---

Notes:

1. on **Ubuntu**, the above procedure *does* end up with a plot.
2. The following URLs were pursued, but did not produce any sulutions:

   3. https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lynx-dev/1998-11/msg00346.html
   4. https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lynx-dev/1998-11/msg00342.html
   5. http://redmine.emweb.be/issues/818
   6. http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=30108.0
   7. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672671

### Edit 1:

1. Installed latest Python (2.7.10) on Cygwin: did not solve problem.

Comment: Whoever downgraded my question: could you explain why?

Comment: Not clear why this question is downvoted. I'm having the same problem and cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really a fix to the problem, but it seems that despite the error message if you follow the link that is shown before you are asked to accept the cookies (for me it was https://plot.ly/~MYUSERNAME/9) it will still show an updated version of the graph you are creating.

Comment: Did you recreate my issue on _cygwin?_ Which browser is `plotly` using on your cygwin? In **my** cygwin, plotly uses `lynx`, which does _not_ show any URL befor asking to accept the first cookie.

Comment: Yes, I recreated this problem using cygwin. My cygwin is also using lynx, but on mine before the page opens the console shows messages like "using page..." and " HTTP request sent ...". If this is not happening at all for you, try checking your plotly profile page, I also found all of my recent projects (even the ones I was getting errors) there.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off automatically opening your browser by adding "auto_open=False" parameter to plotly.plot call. For example:

```
plot_url = py.plot(data, filename = 'basic-line', world_readable=False, auto_open=False)
```